# How to incorporate editing features in native camera in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application that allows user to click a photo and upload I want to allow the user to also be able to rotate or crop after they take the image

How can I do it I am new to development any sources or tutorials that can help?

I am developing using Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Apple's sample code on capturing photos [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html).

There is a property named `allowsEditing` in the `UIImagePickerController`. Try playing with that.

Comment: I have set the picker.allowsEditing = YES but it does not give me any option.